# MongoDB adding new field to the sub document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongodb document like below.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57616e718ed5a017089143f2"),
    "subitems" : {
        "1" : "a",
        "2" : "b"
    }
}
```

I was trying to add new fields to "subitems" field.

```
db.items.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("57616e718ed5a017089143f2") }, { $set: { subitems: { 3: "c" } } })
```

Instead of updating the field, its overwriting it like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57616e718ed5a017089143f2"),
    "subitems" : {
        "3" : "c"
    }
}
```

How do i achieve result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57616e718ed5a017089143f2"),
    "subitems" : {
        "1" : "a",
        "2" : "b",
        "3" : "c"
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why do have a string of integers as fields' name?

Comment: @user3100115 its just a dummy data, the original document don't have string of integers as fields' name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**dot notation**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents) to add the field to an embedded document:

```
db.items.update(
    { "_id" : ObjectId("57616e718ed5a017089143f2") }, 
    { "$set": { "subitems.3": "c" } }
)
```

More from the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents).